# Create a view in SQL Server and lookup with another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm very new to SQL and am trying to create a view in SQL Server using 2 tables.
There are some conditions will impact the way of selecting data and I would appreciate some guidance on what's the logic to create a view for my requirements.

**Condition**: if the `Description` in `Table1` is more than 10 characters and the character from the 9th to 11th are all numbers (3 numbers), then lookup in `Table2` with the same `Device_Name` and `Number`. If there's a match, select the `Host_Name` (T2) and replace the `Device_Name` in the view.

Example:

"Ethernet100" is more than 10 characters and there are all number from the 9th and 11th, use the number 100 and Device_name to lookup at Table2. Replace the Device_Name with Host_Name and put the Host_Name at the new column in the view [Host_On].

**Table 1**

```
Device_Name    Desrciption      Model 
---------------------------------------------
abc1           Ethernet100      sw1
abc2           Ethernet1/1/1    sw1
abc3           Ethernet         sw1
```

**Table 2**

```
Device_Name    Number   Model   Host_Name
-----------------------------------------
abc1           100      sw2     efg
```

Desired result:

```
Device_Name    Description      Model   Host_On
------------------------------------------------
efg            Ethernet100      sw2     abc1
abc2           Ethernet1/1/1    sw1     [NULL]
abc3           Ethernet         sw1     [NULL]
```

Any advice or small part of code is appreciated.

Comment: Can you have alphabetical characters on 9th to 11th? btw you shouldn't save aditional data in description, you should fix your db and create a separated field for it.

Comment: It's implicit in the posted answers so far, but you don't need to worry about the length of the description. The `substring` function won't return matching results if the characters aren't there to find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SUBSTRING` return empty string if string shorter than required.

`TRY_CONVERT()` return `NULL` if string isn't numeric

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ba41c/18)**

```
SELECT   COALESCE (t2.Host_Name, t1.Device_Name) as Final_Device_Name
       , t1.[Description]
       , COALESCE (t2.Model, t1.Model) as Final_Model
       , t2.[Device_Name] as Host_On
       , SUBSTRING(t1.[Description], 9, 3) result       

FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
  ON TRY_CONVERT( INT, SUBSTRING(t1.[Description], 9, 3)) = [Number];
```

**OUTPUT**
as you can see 1/1 doesnt match anything and get Host `NULL`

```
| Final_Device_Name |   Description | Final_Model | Host_On | result |
|-------------------|---------------|-------------|---------|--------|
|               efg |   Ethernet100 |         sw2 |    abc1 |    100 |
|              abc2 | Ethernet1/1/1 |         sw1 |  (null) |    1/1 |
|              abc3 |      Ethernet |         sw1 |  (null) |        |
```

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in the comments your database is lacking some normalization. Not entirely sure what you are trying to do but this should be a push in the right direction.

```
select Device_Name = isnull(t2.Host_Name, t1.Device_Name)
    , t1.Description
    , Model = isnull(t2.Model, t1.Model)
    , Host_On = case when t2.Device_Name is not null then t1.Device_Name end
from Table1 t1
left join Table2 t2 on substring(t1.Device_Name, 9, 3) = convert(varchar(50), t2.Number) --added the convert here as I don't know the datatype for the column
```

Answer (score 0):

### Here is the solution

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Solution_View]
AS
    SELECT tbl1.Device_Name AS Device_Name, tbl1.Desrciption, tbl1.Model, 
    (CASE WHEN (LEN(tbl1.Desrciption) > 10 AND SUBSTRING(tbl1.Desrciption, 10, 3) LIKE '%[^0-9]%') THEN tbl2.Host_Name ELSE NULL END) AS Host_On FROM dbo.Table_1 tbl1
    INNER JOIN dbo.Table_2 tbl2 ON tbl1.Id = tbl1.Id
```

Enjoy your coding

Comment: tables doesnt have id